# Label as Parameter in a Win Form

Tags: asp.net

I have this label thats pulling info from ID of URL..

```
type here
```

```
<asp:Label ID="lblHouse" runat="server"     
       Font-Bold="True" Font-Color="BLue" 
       Font-Size="Large"><%= Request.QueryString["id"] %></asp:Label>
```

I then want to use it as a Parameter in a sql Query for a Datagrid.
It is not brining any results up in the query.  I am using a ID field in the database to ID field in the Sql Query.  Is it a field type issue?

Can you make a asp: label a Sql Parameter?